# MemoryCache always return null after domain unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a issue with the MemoryCache (System.Runtime.Caching). With other questions about this object, I discover that no value are cached after an domain unhandled exception.

The exception is :

```
Exception: System.TypeInitializationException 
Message: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil' threw an exception. 
Trace: 
at System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil.RunInNullExecutionContext(Action callback) 
at System.Web.Hosting.ObjectCacheHost.System.Runtime.Caching.Hosting.IMemoryCacheManager.UpdateCacheSize(Int64 size, MemoryCache memoryCache) 
at System.Runtime.Caching.CacheMemoryMonitor.GetCurrentPressure() 
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryMonitor.Update() 
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStatistics.CacheManagerThread(Int32 minPercent) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx) 
at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)

Caused by Exception: System.Exception Message: Type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext' does not have a public property named 'PreAllocatedDefault'. 
Trace: at System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil.GetDummyDefaultEC() 
at System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil..cctor()
```

The exception seems to be throw  after 2 to 5 minutes. I think solve this exception should sove my issue, because the cache will not be disposed.

The issue started from yesterday 19h even if I use it since 3 months...
No change has been made on the production since 12 days. The server is hosted on Azure (os is Windows Server 2008 R2)

**Editing**
Exception Handler

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Global_UnhandledException);
        System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().DomainUnload += new EventHandler(Global_DomainUnload);
    }
}
```

MemoryCache Wrapper

```
    public abstract class MemoryCacheManager : ICacheManager
{

    private MemoryCache MemoryCache;

    protected MemoryCacheManager()
    {
        MemoryCache = new MemoryCache("Common.Utils.MemoryCacheManager");
    }

    private void ItemRemoved(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        switch (arguments.RemovedReason)
        {
            case CacheEntryRemovedReason.CacheSpecificEviction:
                LogManager.Instance.Log(arguments.CacheItem.Key + " : CacheSpecificEviction");
                break;
            case CacheEntryRemovedReason.ChangeMonitorChanged:
                LogManager.Instance.Log(arguments.CacheItem.Key + " : ChangeMonitorChanged");
                break;
            case CacheEntryRemovedReason.Evicted:
                LogManager.Instance.Log(arguments.CacheItem.Key + " : Evicted");
                break;
            case CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired:
                LogManager.Instance.Log(arguments.CacheItem.Key + " : Expired");
                break;
            case CacheEntryRemovedReason.Removed:
                LogManager.Instance.Log(arguments.CacheItem.Key + " : Removed");
                break;
        }

    }

    #region ICacheManager        
    public void Add(string key, object value, DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration)
    {
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = absoluteExpiration, RemovedCallback = ItemRemoved };
        Add(key, value, policy);
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value, TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
    {
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = slidingExpiration, RemovedCallback = ItemRemoved };
        Add(key, value, policy);
    }

    private void Add(string key, object value, CacheItemPolicy policy)
    {
        MemoryCache.Add(key, value, policy);
        LogManager.Instance.Info(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " " + key + " : Added");
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        return MemoryCache.Get(key);
    }

    public bool Exist(string key)
    {
        return MemoryCache.Contains(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        return MemoryCache.Remove(key) != null;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Cache Manager

```
    public class CacheManager : MemoryCacheManager
{

    #region Singleton
    private static readonly CacheManager instance = new CacheManager();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler ot to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static CacheManager() { }

    private CacheManager() 
        : base()
    {
    }

    public static CacheManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

After first call of Global_UnhandledException, all  CacheManager.Instance.Get return null.

My question is : how to avoid this exception ? Or how to make the memorycache working normaly

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where is the code?

Comment: I edit the question for you

Comment: Which execution model are you using? Web Sites? Cloud Services? Virtual Machines?

Comment: Do you really need the memory cache? Have you seen the new Windows Azure Cache Service? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/09/03/windows-azure-new-distributed-dedicated-high-performance-cache-service-more-cool-improvements.aspx

Comment: It's a web app. I'm using IHttpHandler and RouteTable to reduce stack and optimize the response time.

Comment: The memory cache is enough for us. We have only one instance, so we don't need a shared cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have encountered the exception, which I was able to output to a text file using a HTTP module to capture the unhandled exception, which tends to happen outside of a page request/response execution.

```
message=The type initializer for 'System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil' threw an exception.
stack= at System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil.RunInNullExecutionContext(Action callback)
at System.Web.Hosting.ObjectCacheHost.System.Runtime.Caching.Hosting.IMemoryCacheManager.UpdateCacheSize(Int64 size, MemoryCache memoryCache)
at System.Runtime.Caching.CacheMemoryMonitor.GetCurrentPressure()
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryMonitor.Update()
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStatistics.CacheManagerThread(Int32 minPercent)
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStatistics.CacheManagerTimerCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)

type=System.Exception

message=Type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext' does not have a public property named 'PreAllocatedDefault'.

stack=at System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil.GetDummyDefaultEC()
at System.Web.Util.ExecutionContextUtil..cctor()
```

Edit: It is worth noting that after this exception is thrown caching stops working altogether.

I came across this when researching the problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/11/august-2013-windows-azure-guest-os-issue-with-system-runtime-caching-memorycache.aspx

In the text they say: "This OS release contains the standard security patches, including the fix in https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2862772 (MS13-059) which is a cumulative security update for Internet Explorer.  This IE patch introduced a regression which causes the above exception when using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in an ASP.NET application."

And later, they give three solutions, the first is to rollback before the hotfix was applied. The second tells you to simply avoid using MemoryCache (nice one). And the only other solution is simply waiting until they patch this problem and hint at early October (2013).

"The next Windows Azure Guest OS Release will include the IE hotfix to resolve this issue and should begin rolling out to Azure by early October."

The way this page is presented makes it sound as though this problem is only a problem for Windows Azure. But I think it will affect any platform that has this hotfix and runs an ASP.NET application. Though a 'critical' update for Windows 7 (which is my OS) it seems the hotfix rolled out to Windows Server 2008 is marked as 'moderate'. This may be helpful because although it affects my development platform, it does not affect my production server. I found this information in the security bulletin below:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms13-059

Interestingly I stopped having this issue when I had to add a solution for using OutputCache for child actions in my ASP.NET application, though I'm still inheriting from MemoryCache.

I will include the code I've used, if it comes in handy, and I credit the following blog with saving me a lot of time with this:

http://www.haneycodes.net/custom-output-caching-with-mvc3-and-net-4-0-done-right/

Code below...

```
public class CustomMemoryCache : MemoryCache
    {
    public CustomMemoryCache(string name)
        : base(name)
        {
        }

    public override bool Add(string key, object value, DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration, string regionName = null)
        {
        System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.Providers[System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.DefaultProviderName].Add(key, value, absoluteExpiration.DateTime);
        return true;
        }

    public override object Get(string key, string regionName = null)
        {
        return System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.Providers[System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.DefaultProviderName].Get(key);
        }
    }
```

And in my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new CustomMemoryCache("MyCache");
    }
```

And a provider:

```
public class MyCacheItem
    {
    public Object ItemData { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcExpiry { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcAdded { get; set; }
    }

public class MyOutputCacheProvider: OutputCacheProvider
    {
    private readonly Dictionary<String, MyCacheItem> CacheDictionary = new Dictionary<String, MyCacheItem>(); 

    public override object Get(string key)
        {
        lock(CacheDictionary)
            {
            if (!CacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                return null;

            var Item = CacheDictionary[key];

            // Item has expired?
            if (Item.UtcExpiry < DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                Remove(key);
                return null;
                }

            return Item.ItemData;
            }
        }

    public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
        {
        lock (CacheDictionary)
            {
            if (!CacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                MyCacheItem CacheItem = new MyCacheItem
                    {
                        ItemData = entry, 
                        UtcExpiry = utcExpiry,
                        UtcAdded =  DateTime.UtcNow
                    };

                CacheDictionary.Add(key, CacheItem);
                return CacheItem.ItemData;
                }

            var Item = CacheDictionary[key];
            return Item.ItemData;
            }
        }

    public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
        {
        lock (CacheDictionary)
            {
            if (!CacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                Add(key, entry, utcExpiry);
                return;
                }

            CacheDictionary[key].ItemData = entry;
            CacheDictionary[key].UtcExpiry = utcExpiry;
            }
        }

    public override void Remove(string key)
        {
        lock (CacheDictionary)
            {
            if (!CacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                return;

            CacheDictionary.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, web.config:

```
<system.web>        
    <caching>
        <outputCache defaultProvider="MyCache">
            <providers>
                <add name="MyCache" type="MyApp.Namespace.MyOutputCacheProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </outputCache>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response. 
I'm using a custom cache too (with a lower implementation ^^). I think I will use your solution.

Comment: Thanks. Your link has as one of it's work-rounds "Upgrade to OS Family 3 which uses Windows Sever 2012." which we were about to do anyway. So we will use that - thought this info might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

A hotfix has been released for this issue.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/11/august-2013-windows-azure-guest-os-issue-with-system-runtime-caching-memorycache.aspx for more info.

Comment: Ok Thank you. So If I deploy a new instance, I will have the hotfix installed ? (my csfg is osFamily="2" osVersion="*")

Comment: No, for now you must install it yourself via a startup task.  The next Azure OS version will include the fix by default.

Comment: Your link has as one of it's work-rounds "Upgrade to OS Family 3 which uses Windows Sever 2012." which we were about to do anyway. So we will use that - thought this info might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

All in-memory objects will be gone (in-memory session state, cache, static values,...) because unhandled exceptions tear down the process. In case of ASP.Net it means IIS (or dev server) will restart the application and you get no data cached.

Comment: I m ok with this. But the issue is the exception is not directly in my code and the memorycache does not working after